# Migrate Google Workbox setDefaultHandler // setCatchHandler from v2 to v3

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to migrate my old code from google workbox v2 to workbox v3, and i can't use `workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute` because my default route '/' (which is where my appshell is) is a **runtime cache** (because it's for a multilingual website https://www.autovisual.com with languages put in subfolder '/fr', '/es' ... with a unique Service-Worker scoped at '/').

This is the v2 code :

```
workboxSW.router.setDefaultHandler({
    handler: ({
        event
    }) => {
        return fetch(event.request);
    }
 });

workboxSW.router.setCatchHandler({
    handler: ({
        event
    }) => {
        if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
            return caches.match('/');
        }
        return new Response();
    }
});
```

It seems pretty basic : the goal is to catch all request 'navigate' that didn't match any other route and send the cached version, network first, of the url '/'.

For the info in the client js i use :

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        caches.open('rootCacheNetworkFirst').then(function(cache) {
            cache.match('/').then(function(response) {
                if (!response) {
                    cache.add('/');
                }
            });
        });

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
            scope: "/"
        });
    });
}
```

I can't find any example with the new v3 `workbox.routing.setDefaultHandler` and `workbox.routing.setCatchHandler` and i'm stuck :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that using either `setDefaultHandler` or `setCatchHandler` is relevant for that described use case.

To accomplish what you describe, add the following code to your service worker file *after* all other routes are registered. (In Workbox v3, the [first-registered-route](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v2#workbox-routing) takes precedence.) You just need to configure a [`NavigationRoute`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing.NavigationRoute) and register it:

```
const networkFirst = workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
  cacheName: 'your-cache-name',
});
const navigationRoute = new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(networkFirst, {
  // Set blacklist/whitelist if you need more control
  // over which navigations are picked up.
  blacklist: [],
  whitelist: [],
});
workbox.router.registerRoute(navigationRoute);
```